# SharpDX numbered classes, where do i find their respective documentation/responsibilities?

Tags: directx, sharpdx

I'm having a hard time everytime i look at SharpDX code and try to follow DirectX documentation. Is there a place where what each of the numbered classes map to and why they exist is clearly laid out?

I'm talking about things like :

```
            DXGI.Device
            DXGI.Device1
            DXGI.Device2
            DXGI.Device3
            DXGI.Device4

            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device1
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device11On12
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device2
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device3
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device4
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device5

            SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext1
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext2
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext3
            SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext4
```

Everytime i start from code i find it seems to be picked by black magic and i have no idea where to go from there, for example i'm using this (from code i found) and i have no idea why it's device3, factory 3 going with swapchain1 on which we queryinterface swapchain2 :

```
        using (DXGI.Device3 dxgiDevice3 = this.device.QueryInterface<DXGI.Device3>())
        using (DXGI.Factory3 dxgiFactory3 = dxgiDevice3.Adapter.GetParent<DXGI.Factory3>())
        {

            DXGI.SwapChain1 swapChain1 = new DXGI.SwapChain1(dxgiFactory3, this.device, ref swapChainDescription);
            this.swapChain = swapChain1.QueryInterface<DXGI.SwapChain2>();
        }
```

If full explanation is too large of a the scope of an answer here any link to get me started on figuring out what C++ DX maps to which numbered object and why is most welcome.

In case this matters i'm only interested in DX >= 11, and i'm using SharpDX within an UWP project.

Comment: FWIW, I had the same issue to match SharpDX with the native stuff. That's why I created this "DirectN" project: https://github.com/smourier/DirectN that defines more than 6000 .NET (C#) classes with the exact same names as what you can find in the Windows SDK. Much easier to work with IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharpDx is a pretty thin wrapper around DirectX, and pretty much everything in DirectX is expressed in SharpDx as a pass-through with some naming and calling conventions to accommodate the .net world.

Real documentation on SharpDx is essentially nonexistent, so you will have to do what everybody else does. If you are starting with something in SharpDx then look directly at the SharpDx API listings and the header files to understand what underlying DirectX functions are being expressed.  Once you have the name of the DirectX function, you can read the MSDN documentation to understand how that function works.  If you are starting with something in DirectX, then look first at MSDN to understand how it works and how it's named, and then go to the SharpDx API and header files to find out how that function is wrapped (named and exposed) in SharpDx.

For the specific question you ask, **SharpDx device numbering identifies the Direct3D version that is being wrapped**.

`Direct3D 11.1 device` ==> `ID3D11Device1` ==> `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device1`

`Direct3D 11.2 device` ==> `ID3D11Device2` ==> `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device2`

`Direct3D 11.3 device` ==> `ID3D11Device3` ==> `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device3`

and so on.

Naturally each version has a slightly different ("improved") interface. Lower version numbers will work pretty much anywhere, and higher version numbers include additional functionality that may require something specific from your video card and/or your operating system.  You can read about the API for each version in sections found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/_direct3d11/).

For example, the description of the new methods added to the ID3D11Device5 interface (i.e, what's new since ID3D11Device4) is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11_4/nn-d3d11_4-id3d11device5). In this case, Device5 adds the ability to create a fence object and to open a handle for a shared fence.

When example code uses a specific device number, it's usually because the code requires some functionality that wasn't there in a previous version of Direct3D. In general you want to use the lowest numbered device (and factory, etc.) possible, because that will permit your code to run on the widest variety of machines and video cards.

If you find example code that creates a `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device1` but doesn't appear to use any methods beyond those in `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device`, it's probably for one of two reasons. First, the author may know that a later example will require a method or field that doesn't exist before Direct3D 11.1. Second, the author may know that every video card and operating system capable of running the example at all will be capable of running Direct3D 11.1.

For a person just starting out, I would suggest you just stick with Direct3D (and Direct2D) version 11.1, thus `DXGI.Device1`, `SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device1` and `SharpDX.Direct3D11.DeviceContext1`.  These are likely to run on any machine you'll encounter. Only increase the version number if you actually need some functionality that doesn't appear in that version.

One additional hint: if you read a thread about some Direct3D or Direct2D functionality and you can't seem to find it anywhere in SharpDx, look at the Direct3D API to see what version number first contains that functionality. Then go through the SharpDx API (or better yet the header files) for that version until you see a similarly named element. It may be wrapped in an unexpected way, but AFAIK it's all exposed, even when you have a hard time finding it.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful! Actually this post would probably be a good drop-in replacement for the current sharpdx documentation as i know there’s no need to look elsewhere for it and it gives good guideline on which interface to use instead of picking one without explanations!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://sharpdx.org/wiki/class-library-api/) you can find about all SharpDx objects, specifically for `DXGI` you can found [here](http://sharpdx.org/wiki/class-library-api/dxgi/), There you can see the `Device` mapped to `IDXGIDevice`.
Note the words `IDXGIDevice` are **hyperlink** that references to documentation for C++ object. And on this way `Device1` and `Device2` etc.

You can see that there is a very simple logic here, `SharpDx` divides the name of the C++ object into `Namespace` and a `class name`,
For example instead of `IDXGIDevice`, you get Namespace: `DXG` and class Name: `Device`.

In the documentation for each C++ object you can find [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/DXGI/nn-dxgi-idxgidevice1#requirements).
And there is detailed in which operating system you can use the object.
As the number is higher, the object will work in a newer operating system.
For example, `IDXGIDevice1` works under `Windows 7`, however `IDXGIDevice3` works under `Windows 8.1` or higher.

Comment: I guess this turns it into more of a DirectX than SharpDX issue but i still don't get how to figure out which number i need each time. Should i just use the highest (switching everything to the highest in my project seems to work)? Lowering those numbers leads to crashes, how do i know which "IDXGIDevice" or "ID3D11Device" i want? I assume i don't need to read the whole DX doc for all interfaces just to get a simple rotating triangle on screen and in the sample code i've seen there's no explanation for which interface is picked each time.